How to Schedule Emails Using Python Script(SMTP Protocol)?
I’m working on a Python script to send emails using the SMTP protocol. I want to schedule these emails to be sent at specific times without manually adding time delays in the script(e.g., using time.sleep(), using schedule).
I’ve looked into various libraries and methods but haven’t found a clear solution. Could someone guide me on how to implement this functionality?
Here’s a brief overview of what I’m trying to achieve:
Schedule emails to be sent at specific times.
Use the SMTP protocol for sending emails.
Avoid manually adding time delays (e.g., using time.sleep(), using schedule, using cron job).

Neither Python nor SMTP contain facilities for code to be run at a different point in time. If an explicit sleep is unacceptable, all you can hope for are solutions which obfuscate the explicit sleep with something more implicit.

You can use python schedule module to achieve that. If you don't want to add time or date manually, then you can use a database or JSON to define your schedules.
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

# Run job every 3 second/minute/hour/day/week,
# Starting 3 second/minute/hour/day/week from now
schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job)
schedule.every(3).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every(3).hours.do(job)
schedule.every(3).days.do(job)
schedule.every(3).weeks.do(job)

# Run job every minute at the 23rd second
schedule.every().minute.at(":23").do(job)

# Run job every hour at the 42nd minute
schedule.every().hour.at(":42").do(job)

# Run jobs every 5th hour, 20 minutes and 30 seconds in.
# If current time is 02:00, first execution is at 06:20:30
schedule.every(5).hours.at("20:30").do(job)

# Run job every day at specific HH:MM and next HH:MM:SS
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30:42").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("12:42", "Europe/Amsterdam").do(job)

# Run job on a specific day of the week
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

Source: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html
